# Return all the keys (as set) from num_dict that have value greater than or equal to min_cutoff

Tags: python, dictionary

Parameters

```
num_dict: dictionary
  all values are numeric
min_cutoff: float
```

Compare with the `num_dict` values. Return all keys where their values >= min_cutoff.

My dictionary is `{'Denver': 200, 'Houston': 100, 'NOLA':50}`

```
def keys_get_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff):
    for k, v in num_dict.items():
        if v >= min_cutoff:
            print(keys_get_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong in my solution and algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411815/what-is-wrong-in-my-solution-and-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

```
def keys_get_cutoff(dict, min_value):

    return [key for key in dict.keys() if dict[key] >= min_value]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension. [see more details about list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

**Ex.**

```
num_dict =  {'Denver': 200, 'Houston': 100, 'NOLA':50}
min_cutoff = 51
num_dict_keys = [k for k, v in num_dict.items() if v >= min_cutoff ]
print(num_dict_keys)
```

**O/P:**

```
['Denver', 'Houston']
```