# What is wrong in my solution and algorithm

Tags: python

Returns all the keys (as a set) from `num_dict` that have
value greater than or equal to `min_cutoff`.

**Parameters**:

- num_dict: dictionary. All the values in num_dict are numeric.
- min_cutoff: float. Comparison with the num_dict values. Return all keys, where
  their values >= min_cutoff.
- set: All keys from `num_dict` whose values meet the cutoff criterion.

**Examples**:

```
keys_geq_cutoff({'Alice': 21, 'Brett': 20, 'Carlos': 31}, 21)
{'Alice', 'Carlos'}
```

My code:

```
def keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff):
    for k, v in num_dict.items():
        if (v >= min_cutoff):
            return(keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff))
```

ERROR:

```
test_keys_geq_cutoff (test_methods.TestPython1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/test_methods.py", line 13, in test_keys_geq_cutoff
    result1 = main.keys_geq_cutoff(test_d, 0)
  File "/usr/src/app/main.py", line 4, in keys_geq_cutoff
    return(keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff))
  File "/usr/src/app/main.py", line 4, in keys_geq_cutoff
    return(keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff))
  File "/usr/src/app/main.py", line 4, in keys_geq_cutoff
    return(keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff))
  [Previous line repeated 956 more times]
  File "/usr/src/app/main.py", line 3, in keys_geq_cutoff
    if (v >= min_cutoff):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are calling the function again in your return statement with exactly the same arguments and hence the `RecursionError`. You need to collect the keys inside a set and then return that set:

```py
def keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff):
    res = set()
    for k, v in num_dict.items():
        if (v >= min_cutoff):
            res.add(k)
    return res
```

alternatively, a nice set-comprehension could be in use:

```py
def keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff):
    return {k for k, v in num_dict.items() if v >= min_cutoff}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're having a recursion error, which means that you're calling the function itself in the body of the function without providing an exit clause, so the function will go on for ever. to solve this you have to make an exit clause (for example an if statement)

But you probably don't want to use that technique

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
def keys_geq_cutoff(num_dict, min_cutoff):
    l = []
    for k, v in num_dict.items():
        if v >= min_cutoff:
            l.append(k)
    return set(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a function for that? The problem looks quite similiar to:
[Return all the keys (as set) from num_dict that have value greater than or equal to min_cutoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103239/return-all-the-keys-as-set-from-num-dict-that-have-value-greater-than-or-equal)

you could use a one coder for this:

```
num_dict =  {'Alice': 21, 'Brett': 20, 'Carlos': 31}
min_cutoff = 21
num_dict_keys = [k for k, v in num_dict.items() if v >= min_cutoff ]
print(num_dict_keys)
```

Comment: What's wrong with a one-line function? and that creates a list, not a set